# Load data from ubuntu to router's UPnP DLNA server

Tags: 12.04, networking, mediaserver, dlna, upnp

I set up a mini-DLNA server on my router with dd-wrt.  I have a bunch of music and other media files I would like to be able to stream from my router-attached USB drive to my stereo and Android devices.

This media is currently stored on my Ubuntu device.  I don't particularly want the Ubnuntu device to have a media server (I think because security? though a media client would be fine), however, I can't see how to get the files onto the drive without turning my Ubuntu device into a media server.

Can anyone point me to some easy instructions for how to dump several folders of video and audio files onto the router's mini-dlna upnp server?  I'm using 12.04 if that helps.

Comment: See the following related questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/109505/how-do-i-access-an-external-hard-drive-plugged-into-my-router http://askubuntu.com/questions/325132/help-how-to-connect-to-hard-drive-that-is-connected-to-router http://askubuntu.com/questions/11027/sharing-files-with-a-dd-wrt-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tackle the security problem: add a new user to your ubuntu system and place a media server into this new user's space.

Copy the media you want to stream on an USB device and then into the new user's folder.